# Recover data from columns DC2Type:array

Tags: php

Have a column with this format "DC2Type:array" in symphony try to read data as array but receive a Null.

my function is:

```
public function getData()
{
    return $this->data;
}
```

need some particular way or is another inconvenient different.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check your data is set or not: example code

```
public $data ;

public function getData()
{
    return $this->data;
}

public function setData($data)
{
    return $this->data = $data;
}
```